# ¿Como puedo guardar un dato especifico en una URL dentro de visual studio para guardarla en una variable?

Tags: c#, sap

Como puedo obtener un dato especifico en una url que me llega respuesta de una solicitud que estoy realizando en sap, ya que necesito ese dato en especifico para poder guardarla en la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando para enviar los datos y sap y crear una orden de venta en la ERP lo que sigue es obtener el numero que muestro en la imagen para guardarla en una variable y este sea almacenada en la base de datos que estoy usando para poder despues editar, eliminar o realizar otro tipo de consultas con mis sistema

```
    public void OrdenDeVenta(PedidoViewModel pedido, List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedido)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Login");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Timeout = 1000;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;


        var login = new LoginSAP
        {
            UserName = "sap",
            Password = "1234",
            CompanyDB = "SBOSoindusCL"
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login, Formatting.Indented);
        using (var streamWriter = new 
        System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 
        System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidarCertificado);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        string Cookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"].ToString();

        string strB1Session = string.Empty;
        string strCurrRouteId = string.Empty;

        if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cookie))
        {
            int idx = Cookie.IndexOf("B1SESSION=");
            if (idx >= 0)
            {
                string strSubString = Cookie.Substring(idx);
                int idxSplitter = strSubString.IndexOf(";");
                if (idxSplitter > 0)
                {
                    strB1Session = strSubString.Substring(0, idxSplitter);
                }
                else
                {
                    strB1Session = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            int idx2 = Cookie.IndexOf("ROUTEID=");
            if (idx2 > 0)
            {
                string strSubString = Cookie.Substring(idx2);
                int idxSplitter = strSubString.IndexOf(";");
                if (idxSplitter > 0)
                {
                    strCurrRouteId = strSubString.Substring(0, idxSplitter);
                }
                else
                {
                    strCurrRouteId = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        string strFormat = "{0};{1}";
        string strCookie = string.Format(strFormat, strB1Session, strCurrRouteId);

        HttpWebRequest request2 = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Orders");
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.ContentType = "application/json";
        request2.Timeout = 1000;
        request2.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request2.Headers.Add("Cookie", strCookie);


        using (var streamWriter = new 
        System.IO.StreamWriter(request2.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            var oferta = new Oferta();
            oferta.CardCode = pedido.CodigoSAP_Cliente;
            oferta.DocDate = pedido.Fecha; 
            oferta.NumAtCard = pedido.Numero;
            oferta.DocDueDate = pedido.FechaEntrega;
            oferta.DocumentLines = new List<DocumentLine>();
            foreach (var item in listaPedido)
            {
                oferta.DocumentLines.Add(
                    new DocumentLine
                    {
                        ItemCode = item.Codigo,
                        DiscountPercent = item.Descuento,
                        TaxCode = "IVA_EXE",
                        Quantity = item.Cantidad,
                        UnitPrice = item.Precio
                    }
                );

            }
            string ofertaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oferta, 
        Formatting.Indented);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(ofertaJson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }


        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 
        System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidarCertificado);
        WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();
        request2.KeepAlive = true;
        Console.WriteLine(response2.ToString());
        var location = response2.Headers["Location"].ToString();//Aqui es donde obtengo la localizacion de la url 

        HttpWebRequest request3 = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://.85.239.243:50000/b1s/v1/Logout");
        request3.Method = "POST";
        request3.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request2.KeepAlive = false;
        request3.Timeout = 1000;
        request3.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request3.Headers.Add("Cookie", strCookie);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new 
        System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidarCertificado);
        WebResponse response3 = request3.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response3).StatusDescription);
    }
```

Comment: Y digo yo.. que te impide parsear el string como cualquier otro?

Comment: Como te comentan debes parsar el string de la url (idem a lo que se realiza en tu codigo que muestras con los valores de las cookies en la parte de que utiliza Substring). Lo que no se es todo el codigo que muestras hace varias cosas, seria bueno que solo coloques la parte de de la URL qu eno se exactamente cual es, y que pruebes esto de "parsear/manipular" el string para obtener un valor

Comment: si supiera no estaria posteando algo relacionado pero gracias por la info aunque ya encontre otra forma de hacerlo :)